# How to export statistics from SoapUI load test via groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui, load-testing, groovyscriptengine

I have a working project with load test.

```
def loadTest = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Load").getTestCaseByName(testCaseSelect).getLoadTestByName(loadTestSelect)

loadTest.run().waitUntilFinished()
```

I need to export statistics from this place:
[image: soapUiScreenShoot]

I tried

```
def testResults = loadTest.getStatistics()
testResults.exportToCsv("C:/Users/tester/Desktop/statistics.csv")
```

but I'm receiving an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.WsdlLoadTest.getStatistics() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getStatisticsModel() error at line: 92
```

I asked ChatGPT but any solutions didn't work (maybe my prompts were incorrect :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, maybe ChatGPT is garbage

From looking at the Javadoc [here](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/loadtest/WsdlLoadTest.html#getStatisticsModel--) and [here](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/loadtest/data/actions/ExportStatisticsAction.html), have you tried

```
def testResults = loadTest.getStatisticsModel()
new ExportStatisticsAction(testResults).exportToFile(new File("C:/Users/tester/Desktop/statistics.csv"))
```

Not tested it, but it's from actual help docs, not imagined by a statistical model of words

Comment: Thanks, 
it works. 

I needed add an import
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.data.actions.ExportStatisticsAction